How to Install Catch2 on Win11 VS using CMakeList ? - files not found : Catch2Config.cmake & catch2-config.cmake
I create 2 small cmake projects on VS.

1st project : MyCatch2installer - goal to install Catch2 independently
of other C++ project.
2nd project: CMakeProject1 - goal to test
access to Catch at the CMake level

`
   #################################

    #1st Project

    project ("MyCatch2Installer")
 
    # Source: https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/cmake-integration.md

    set(CATCH2_VERSION 3.7.0)

    Include(FetchContent)

    FetchContent_Declare(
      Catch2
      GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2.git
      GIT_TAG        v${CATCH2_VERSION}
    )

    FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Catch2)

  #################################

    #2nd Project

    project ("CMakeTestProject1")

    list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/temp/MyCatch2Installer/out/build/x64-debug")

    find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)

    #################################

`
Part of the error message on find_package is :

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Catch2" with
any   of the following names:
Catch2Config.cmake
catch2-config.cmake


And after having checked, they have not be installed by the "MyCatch2Installer" Cmakelist.
At the execution of MyCatch2Installer i read the console message:
1> [CMake] -- Build files have been written to: C:/temp/MyCatch2Installer/out/build/x64-debug
Last thing : i am using VisualStudioVersion=17.0

I don't see anything calling install in the snippet you posted.

"Build files have been written to" - This denotes the end of the configuration step. Following cmake --build performs building the project, and following cmake --install performs the installation. For make find_package to work properly, the project should be installed.
